# Subversion doubts?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Hi I want to install subversion in my office. A lot of other teams will use the same repository for which I have some doubts.

Do I need to install it on a server or a virtual server so that everyone can work on it?

What should I use SVN client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I prefer collabnet SVN  http://www.collab.net/support/support-programs

Follow below steps to install SVN for your org/team.

1. Download collabnet/other SVN vendor software and install it any
   Linux servers.
2. Configure your server(repository) available via Web/ssh+
3. Ask your team members to install SVN clients like tortoise/web svn/..any tool
   to access repository.

if you have any issues in installation post here, will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing [UberSVN](http://www.wandisco.com/ubersvn/download#windows) in any server or PC from your office, it's an easy implementation of SVN. And using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) as a client in the other machines ot the IDE's respective plugins.

The other machines will connect to the IP os the "server" machine.

Comment: UberSVN product hasn't been updated for a year or so.